# How to assign a list/tuple as argument of a python function

Tags: list, arguments, tuples, typeerror, symbolic-math

I am trying to estimate numerical estimate of a large symbolic expression that is composed of a varying number of arguments (for e.g. 21 here, but assume an unknown number of variables for other expressions). So, I use `sym.lambdify()` to convert the symbolic expression (`expression_sym`) to a python function (`fn_expression`) that I can use to find a numerical estimate for its corresponding symbolic expression (`expression_sym`).

```
import sympy as sym
symbols_tuple = tuple(expression_sym.free_symbols)
fn_expression = sym.lambdify(symbols_tuple, expression_sym)
```

Now I source constant numerical values for all symbols present in `symbols_tuple` in a variable called `free_symbols_val`. However, `free_symbols_val` also contains some other variable names that are not present in `symbols_tuple`.

```
free_symbols_val = foo() # numerical values for all symbols from some function foo()
```

Now that I have all the numerical values for all the symbols/variables present in `fn_expression`, I can simply pass the variable names that are known to be part of `expression_sym`. I cannot directly use `free_symbols_val` as input because it contains more variables than present in `fn_expression`.

```
fn_num = fn_expression(symbols_tuple)
```

However, using `symbols_tuple` directly as an argument for `fn_expression()` gives a TypeError as follow:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 21 arguments (1 given)
```

### Note:

I know about `*args` in python that can be used to assign an unknown number of arguments, but that is not working here, i.e. if I use `fn_expression(*symbols_tuple)` it doesn't work and throws the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Comment: You're on the right path (about using `*symbols_tuple`), but it seems that some of the values in the `tuple` are incorrect. Please add the full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: I checked the values in the `tuple`, and it contains all values. I checked the symbols by `tuple(expression_sym.free_symbols)` and then obtained their constant values.

Comment: Obviously somewhere in there someone is specting a `float` and receiving something else. Can you post the full stacktrace?